# Prevent DOS prompt when using emacs as an 'alternate editor'

Tags: microsoft-windows

I have activated in Alpine email client the following setting in order to use Emacs as an editor when composing emails:

```
[X]  Enable Alternate Editor Implicitly
Editor                              = emacs.exe
```

When I start to compose a message, by putting the cursor below the following area in Alpine

```
----- Message Text -----
```

Emacs will be started. But a DOS prompt (with the title C:\Program Files\GNU Emacs 24.4\bin\emacs.exe) is also opened at the same time.

My question is how to prevent this prompt from being opened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Comment to answer**

There's a program called `runemacs.exe` under Windows, that should prevent the DOS prompt from being opened.